# LiipImagineBundle error

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, bundle, liipimaginebundle

I'm installing the bundle LiipImagineBundle for my symfony project.
I added it in the kernel, config it :

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
    default:
        web_path: ~
filter_sets:
    avatar:
        quality: 75
        cache: ~
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [120, 120], mode: outbound }
```

When i'm launching a page with a form in it, i got this error :

```
Unable to find template "LiipImagineBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig" (looked into: /Users/user/www/html/project/app/Resources/views, /Users/user/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).
```

Why ? Can you help me to find the problem ? And when i delete the config and kernel for LiipImagineBundle, it's working again.

Thanks by advance,

Edit : 
I'm working on the v3.4.1 of symfony.

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
"symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
"twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
"jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.3.0",
"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^4.0.1",
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3.0",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0.2",
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2.2",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.3.1",
"lexik/maintenance-bundle": "^2.1.2",
"liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.9.1",
"nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13.3",
"nietonfir/google-recaptcha-bundle": "^0.2.1",
"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0.20"
```

Comment: Please share the version of Symfony and LiipImagineBundle you are using. (you can share composer.json if you want).

Comment: have you cleared your cache ?

Comment: Clearing the cache don't do anything :(

Comment: Is the reference to the form template in your code or part of the bundle itself?  S3.4/4.0 has made some tweaks to template directories.  Seen a few recent questions on this sort of thing.

Comment: It's directly in the twig : `Twig_Error_Loader in app/Resources/views/default/user_informations.html.twig (line 21)
=> {{ form_start(form_address) }}`

Comment: Not sure what that means but try using the twig namespace path: "@LiipImagine\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig" and see if that helps.

Comment: Oops.  Forward slash not back slash: "@LiipImagine/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig"

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: I just did a fresh install of a project and it seems to work.  Consider updating your question with a few lines from user_informations.html.twig showing where form div file is being included.  Could be a simple typo.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce the problem and found a work around hack.

```
# LiipImagineExtension.php
$resources = $container->hasParameter('twig.form.resources') ? 
$container->getParameter('twig.form.resources') : array();

// The existing line
//$resources[] = 'LiipImagineBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig';

// Change to
$resources[] = '@LiipImagine/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig';

$container->setParameter('twig.form.resources', $resources);
```

So somewhere along the line S3.4 seems to have changed something to only use twig namespaces instead of the colon notation.  Kind of a strange BC break for Symfony.

I checked on liip github.  This is actually fixed in their unreleased 2.0 branch.  Consider updating to "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.0@dev",

This can also be fixed by configuring the framework to use twig:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem exists only if you add new `Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(`) after `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle()`.

The installation guide should highlight the fact that the bundle **should not** be loaded after twig.

In AppKernel.php :

```
// ...
new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
// ...
```

Apparently this problem is solved in the current latest version 2.x